# Como descobrir o que é arquivo e o que é diretório

Tags: linux, script, shell

A pergunta é tão simples quanto a lógica que disponho aqui.

## Lógica:

Supondo que arquivos sempre devem conter seu sufixo .png .txt etc...

Enquanto pastas/diretórios não leva nada além de seu nome sem formato

A idéia é essa, pegar tais nomes referenciados e definir um ícone tipo: se for um diretório, **setar um ícone de pasta**. Agora, se for um arquivo com extensão, **setar um ícone de arquivo**.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Alguém poderia por gentileza me mostrar como posso elaborar um script shell bash de modo a detectar o que é o que dentro de um diretório : arquivo e pasta

Comment: Para arquivos: `[[ -f "seu-arquivo" ]] && echo "É um arquivo"`; para pastas `[[ -d "sua-pasta" ]] && echo "É uma pasta"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O Bash tem um teste embutido que pode ser o que você procura.

Num terminal, numa pasta qualquer, digite:

```
for i in * ; do if [ -d "$i" ] ; then echo "diretório - $i" ; else echo "  arquivo - $i" ; fi ; done
```

Mais detalhes, veja o manual do "bash".

Comment: Diego, nem sempre os arquivos vão ter extensão, e nem sempre os diretórios não terão no final do nome um "ponto alguma coisa" ;)

Comment: @Dudaskank Sei disso, mas acho um pouco complexo fazer a verificação através do cabeçalho de cada arquivo, é o que o bash faz com sua função built-in. Mas tentarei fazer um script com o comando `file` ou `objdump` aliado com `grep` para extrair a informção e definir os respectivos ícones. Somente a nível de aprendizado e conhecimento farei isso.

Comment: Infelizmente, a detecção de arquivos está errada. Coisas como pipes nomeados e outras estruturas não arquivo (ok, normalmente elas moram no `/dev`) vão ser apresentadas como arquivo. O ideal seria ` ; elif [ -f "$i" ]; then echo "arquivo $i"; else echo "outra coisa $i"; fi`

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Não entendi??? Você esta dizendo isso a mim ou para o colega [Francisco](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/282632/41467)?

Comment: @DiegoHenrique seria uma crítica à resposta, inclusive para os leitores dela ficarem cientes de que existe a possibilidade de uma coisa estranha na árvore do sistema de arquivos

Answer (score 2):

Coloco aqui como registro para futura consulta

Detectar arquivos e diretórios/pastas via cabeçalho:

Todos:

```
file *
```

Pastas:

```
file * | grep -i directory
```

Arquivos:

```
file * | grep -i text
```

Detectar somente diretórios/pastas com uso do comando `ls`:

```
ls -alp1 | grep -i "^d" | awk '{print $7}'

ls -d */
```

.. e faz-se com `find` tranzendo subpastas:

```
find ./ -type d
```

Para arquivos *.*:

```
ls -alp1 | grep -i "^-" | awk '{print $7}'
```

Agora, detectar links símbolicos(atalho):

```
ls -alp1 | grep -i "^l" | awk '{print $7}'
```